# Estimating derivatives when given a table

Tags: calculus, derivatives, estimation

When given a table of values such as this:

\begin{array}{|c|ccc|}
\hline
x & 1 & 3 & 7 & 9 & 10 \\ \hline
f(x) & 6 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 15\\ \hline
\end{array}

I want to estimate the value of $f'(7)$, but I'm not sure which way I'm supposed to estimate. For example, I could find the average rate of change over $[3, 7]$, and also over $[7, 9]$, then average the results:

$${f(9)-f(7) \over 9-7} = {2-1\over 9-7} = \frac 12$$
$${f(7)-f(3) \over 7-3} = {1-3\over 7-3} = -\frac 12$$

This results in an average of $0$, thus an estimate $f'(7)\approx 0$. But I could also just take the average rate of change over $[3, 9]$:

$${f(9)-f(3) \over 9-3} = {2-3\over 9-3} = -\frac 16$$

Which gives an estimate of $f'(7) \approx -\frac 16$. Which one should I use, and in which contexts? Does this depend on the function $f$ (such as concavity), and if so, how?

Comment: When I do a numerical approximation I use $\frac {f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}$

Comment: @DougM But this involves unequal subintervals.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single way how to do this. One thing that comes to my mind is to find a polynomial equation (of 4th degree) that passes through these points in your table. Once you have that polynomial equation, you may take a derivative and find $f'(7)$. Note: Even then the result is an estimate because you are not given that the function in question happens to be of polynomial nature. It is just an estimation. But I think it would be a good one. Do you know how to find this polynomial? I can update on that if you wish. Let me know!

Comment: My concern is specifically on AP tests, where it sometimes asks for an approximation. They usually have answers from both techniques of approximation yet they never tell you the reason why either one is better than the other. I'm not sure if I can find a sample, though I'll try.

Comment: But on AP test, do they have multiple choice? And are you allowed to use a graphing calculator?

Comment: Yes, multiple choice sometimes with answers from using either technique which is confusing. I'm guessing it really depends on the circumstances right, since here the subintervals are uneven.

Comment: Yes, indeed it depends on circumstances. That said, do you understand my approach? It is a little algebra (takes some time) but it is not difficult. As far as estimation is concerned, I believe that a polynomial approach is a good one.

Comment: If we're talking in general, sure I understand the polynomial approach, but I'm just wondering if you could maybe outline some circumstances in which either approach presented in the question would work better than the other?

Comment: It depends on the time you have to complete all questions. I have not taken any AP exam in my life so I would not know the nature of the exam. A simple sketch of the points can give you some clue as to which multiple choice answers probably should NOT be it. If it is an open question, then they probably want to see your versatility as to how you would tackle this problem. You second choice of $-1/6$ wouldn't be a bad choice. (In fact, is there really a right/wrong answer?)

Comment: I guess you're right in that respect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Polynomial fitting of degree > 2 can be very risky unless you are certain that the function truly is polynomial. Poly fits will match the data points given but often oscillate wildly in between those points. See e.g. discussion at https://www.maplesoft.com/applications/view.aspx?sid=4373&view=html

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent Yes, I agree. However, we are interpolating $x=7$ so one approach is to use "as much information" as possible, which is to incorporate all points. On the other hand, a sketch may suggest that you may only use the two points on the side, i.e. $x=3$ and $x=9$. If I were a teacher and my student would raise your concern, he would get all the points awarded for the question.

Answer (score 1):

If the curve were approximately parabolic between (3,3), (7,1) and (9,2)

Then $f'(6) = -\frac 16$  The derivative at the midpoint equals slope between the end points.

[image]

Which would suggest picking a bigger number for an estimate of $f'(7)$

Maybe $f'(7) = \frac 16$

But these are all just estimates, and there is no hard-and-fast rule.

Answer (score 0):

For something like an AP test, I think your first approach is better.  Your second one suffers from 7 not being halfway between 3 and 9 or you would get the same results.